# CentOs DB2 client call stored procedure from remote DB2 z/OS server return bad encoding

Tags: php, stored-procedures, character-encoding, centos, db2

On my server installed CentOs 7.3 and DB2 server client (v10.5fp8_linuxx64_client.tar.gz (569.81 MB))
CentOs has locale **en_US.utf8**, *dbset DB2CODEPAGE=* (not set)

I successfully connecting to remote database on z/OS and can select from tables with cyrillic data.
But when i try to call stored procedure that resulting open cursor, all cyrillic fields are limited by 8 symbols.

Also on windows OS with same version client Stored procedure return all symbols fine and readable.

Also when I try to use php and build compiled *pdo_ibm.so* on this installed client, and then call stored procedure from PHP:

```
    $con = "ibm:DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=TEST;HOSTNAME=10.100.10.1;PORT=5120;" 
    //same result if add CHARSET=UTF-8;
    $conPDO = new PDO($con, "login", "pass");
    $sql = "CALL @SOME.TESTSP(1,0,' ',' ',0,' ',' ',?,?);";
    $stmt = $conPDO->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $errorNumber, PDO::PARAM_INT | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $errorCode, PDO::PARAM_STR | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);
    $exec = $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($result as $v) {
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($v['city']);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
```

And on output i have:

[image]

and here I have also 8 symbols normal, but all that after 8 symbols is in bad encoding.

If I change CentOs locale to anything else than *en_US.utf8* I've got this:
[image]

I think problem in CentOs or DB2 linux client maybe. DBAdministrator, that create this SP says that codepage used there is ibm-1025.

But windows DB2 client encoding input data fine.

______________________UPD1:
After using

> db2 terminate ; export LANG=ru_RU; db2 connect to database... ; db2
>   "CALL stored procedure"

Steel got only 8 symbols:
[image]

____UPD2:

LC_CTYPE didn't changes to ru_RU. After export LC_CTYPE=ru_RU all symbols changes to this:

[image]

Also tried set all centOs locale to ru_RU.utf8 (and ru_RU.iso88595) and also got 8 symbols only.

___UPD:

JDBC work fine

Comment: Does it make any difference if you call the stored procedure from Centos command-line (e.g. in ksh or bash) ?    Does it make a difference if you call the stored-procedure from a jdbc4 GUI?  Does it make a difference if you (at the bash command line)  run `db2 terminate ; export LANG=ru_RU;  db2 connect to database... ; db2 "CALL stored procedure" `  ?

Comment: @mao, 
1: how can I call SP in clear bash? I thought it can be done only with *../db2/v10.5/bin/db2*;

2: I have no GUI at all - today will try write some Java app with Jdbc4 that will call SP; 3: Updated question with tests about 3rd.